# Get milliseconds passed

Tags: c#, time, milliseconds

A just need a stable count of the current program's progression in milliseconds in C#. I don't care about what timestamp it goes off of, whether it's when the program starts, midnight, or the epoch, I just need a single function that returns a stable millisecond value that does not change in an abnormal manner besides increasing by 1 each millisecond. You'd be surprised how few comprehensive and simple answers I could find by searching.

Edit: Why did you remove the C# from my title? I'd figure that's a pretty important piece of information.

Comment: Any timer wont give you better resolution than 15.4 milliseconds.

Comment: Anyhow, you will never going to be as accurate in terms of milliseconds every-time.

Comment: Can't you use the [StopWatch Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: @Maurdekye you're right, knowing that this is C# is important. However, we generally put things like that in [tags](http://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) rather than titles. This makes it much easier to search and filter questions.

Comment: Real time, ideally. It doesn't have to be perfectly synchronized with a world clock, just fairly accurate and reliable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your program starts create a [`StopWatch`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and `Start()` it.

```
private StopWatch sw = new StopWatch();

public void StartMethod()
{
  sw.Start();
}
```

At any point you can query the Stopwatch:

```
public void SomeMethod()
{
  var a = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;
}
```

If you want something accurate/precise then you need to use a StopWatch, and please read Eric Lippert's Blog (formerly the Principal Developer of the C# compiler Team) [Precision and accuracy of DateTime](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/04/08/precision-and-accuracy-of-datetime.aspx).

Excerpt:

> Now, the question “how much time has elapsed from start to finish?” is a completely different question than “what time is it right now?” If the question you want to ask is about how long some operation took, and you want a high-precision, high-accuracy answer, then use the StopWatch class. It really does have nanosecond precision and accuracy that is close to its precision.

If you don't need an accurate time, and you don't care about precision and the possibility of edge-cases that cause your milliseconds to actually be *negative* then use DateTime.

Comment: Is this really the simplest method? I know in Java there's a `System.getCurrentTimeMillis()` which you can call at any time to get the milliseconds passed. Is there no equivalent in C#?

Comment: You certainly could do that, but no DateTime methods are [HighResolution](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.ishighresolution(v=vs.110).aspx). I'm not sure why someone would want to measure anything in Milliseconds and then not want it to be accurate..

Comment: You can achieve this by using difference of CurrentProcess, System.Diagnostics.Process.StartTime and DateTime.Now

Comment: @ErikPhilips, yeah I know, I have already said the same in the main comment section.

Comment: I'm going to use your answer, since it seems the simplest and most reliable.

Comment: It's not the simplest and I don't know how you're measuring reliable.  It's going to be the most precise and accurate (not with standing the time to took to start the application, create a stopwatch and start it).

Comment: My answer is the simplest. @ErikPhilips answer will probably yield you the most accurate. So your choice comes down to simplicity vs accuracy.

Comment: @Icemanind accuracy and precision (precision means that under no circumstances will milliseconds actually be incorrect).

Comment: Simplest, ie. I only have to call one method each time I need to know how many milliseconds have passed, even if it requires defining a global variable dedicated to the task at the program's start. It's also easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

You could store the current time in milliseconds when the program starts, then in your function get the current time again and subtract

edit:

if what your going for is a stable count of process cycles, I would use processor clocks instead of time.

as per your comment you can use DateTime.Ticks, which is 1/10,000 of a millisecond per tick

Also, if you wanted to do the time thing you can use DateTime.Now as your variable you store when you start your program, and do another DateTime.Now whenever you want the time. It has a millisecond property.

Either way **DateTime** is what your looking for

Comment: That's great and all, but how do I GET the current time in milliseconds?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean `DateTime.Now`? It holds absolute time, and subtracting two `DateTime` instances gives you a `TimeSpan` object which has a `TotalMilliseconds` property.

Comment: Is there a simpler way? I asked for one function that could do it.

Comment: If subtracting two values is too complicated, I suggest a different programming language.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are just trying to get the current date and time, in milliseconds. If you are just trying to get the current time, in milliseconds, try this:

```
long milliseconds = DateTime.Now.Ticks / TimeSpan.TicksPerMillisecond;
```